# how to find coefficient c1, c2, c3, c4 of a polynomials of degree 4 from resolvent

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, maple

if not starting from standard resolvent of each degree
and use (y-x1...)*(y-x2...)*(y-x3...) and group theory

how to find corresponding c1, c2, c3, c4 of polynomial x^4+c4*x^3+c3*x^2+c2*x+c1 which c1, c2, c3, c4 are in terms of x1, x2, x3, x4  and  x^4+c4*x^3+c3*x^2+c2*x+c1  is separable which means (x-....)*(x....)*(x....)...?

**update1:**

x1,x2,x3,x4 may not be symmetric polynomials,
i see x1*x2 + x3*x4 as permutation group [[1,2],[3,4]]
or x1*x2*x3 + x4 as [[1,2,3],[4]]

david a. cox's book only have an example page 358 about working from x^4+c4*x^3+c3*x^2+c2*x+c1 to resolvent and then group, my question is reverse direction, which means from a set of groups and then resolvent and then one polynomial

if physicist start from group to work out a polynomial, how do they do in real practice?

**update2**

**if not start from x1*x2+x3*x4  this permutation group  [[1,2],[3,4]] , and if start from for example, x1*x2*x3 + x4, resolvent is change to something like  (y-(x1*x2*x3 + x4)) * (y-.....etc, how to find back a polynomial for degree 4.**

Comment: if possible, use degree 3 as example

Comment: Maybe *you* should show *us* an example, since your question is incomprehensible. Anyway, $c_1$ is just $x_1x_2x_3x_4$, $c_4$ is $-(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)$, and so on, if you just multiply out.

Comment: david a. cox's book only have an example page 358 about working from x^4+c4*x^3+c3*x^2+c2*x+c1 to resolvent and then group, my question is reverse direction, which means from a set of groups and then resolvent and then one polynomial

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: if not start from x1*x2+x3*x4  this permutation group  [[1,2],[3,4]] , and if start from for example, x1*x2*x3 + x4, resolvent is change to something like  (y-(x1*x2*x3 + x4)) * (y-.....etc, how to find back a polynomial for degree 4.

Comment: So, are you asking, what are the coefficients of $$(y-(x_1x_2x_3+x_4))(y-(x_1x_2x_4+x_3))(y-(x_1x_3x_4+x_2))(y-(x_2x_3x_4+x_1))$$ And are you asking for the answer in terms of $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$? The answer could be very complicated.

Comment: yes , i am asking for c1 , c2, c3, c4 in terms of x1,x2,x3,x4, i guess this is complicated, the important thing is that i would like to learn the method and steps. because there are many groups. moreover, bonus is that i would like to learn how [[1,2,3],[4]], [1,2,4],[3]],....etc in  your suggestion are related and in another words, how to find these set of group. For simple, you can use maple code instead of using Latex to answer.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, hilbert?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

I think we have established in the comments that part of the question is, given a function $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ of the roots of a polynomial, for example, $x_1x_2x_3+x_4$, how do we find the conjugates of this expression.

The answer is, the conjugates are the expressions $f(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})$, as $\sigma$ runs through all the elements of the group $S_n$.

In the example, and writing elements of $S_n$ in cycle notation, $\sigma=(1\ 4)$ gives us $x_2x_3x_4+x_1$, $\sigma=(2\ 4)$ gives $x_1x_3x_4+x_2$, and $\sigma=(3\ 4)$ yields $x_1x_2x_4+x_3$ (and of course letting $\sigma$ be the identity gets us $x_1x_2x_3+x_4$). There are 20 other elements of $S_4$, but they just give us the same four conjugates over and over.

The other part of the question is how to express $\prod_{\sigma}(y-f(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)}))$ in terms of the coefficients of the original polynomial. I will leave that to someone more proficient in the use of computer algebra systems than myself.